# How to avoid page expires on button or link click. Page expires when I return null for any button click or link on form

Tags: jsf-2

I am using filter that check if user is log in then don't cache the previous page. The code for this is like,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    ....
    if (isRegisteredUser.equalsIgnoreCase(("1"))) {

        sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800); 

        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "loginUser");
        userCookie.setPath("/");
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(userCookie);

        Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("WITSessionCookie", sessionID);
        sessionCookie.setMaxAge(60*30);  
        sessionCookie.setPath("/");    
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(sessionCookie);

        if (!httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpServletRequest.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

    }
    ...

} //end of doFilter()
```

But the problem is, if on any page user click on any button or link, and I return null for that action, and then I click on browser back button, then it says page expires. **How can I prevent this?** It is fine, that the page is not caching, but **why it expires my page when I click on any button or any link and return null for that action?**
Thanks

Comment: Your session and cookie handling is quite strange by the way. You seem so miss some basic concepts on that.

Comment: ...:) What do you mean by basic concepts? can you please tell me about that basic concepts? Yes you are right. Actually i just read it from chapters. But that was for servlets and JSP. And now i am using JSF.  obviously session tracking is same, but yes i lack concepts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal and specified behaviour when the enduser attempts to re-send a POST request which is not cached in the browser. You need to implement the post-redirect-get pattern. Send a redirect to the destination page in the action method. Or, better, make it an ajax submit instead. This is by the way regardless of whether you return to the same view by returning `null` or not.

Comment: How can i implement **post-redirect-get pattern** ? So if my action return null then the page is not expire. Yes i am returning to same view. Let say i have page faq.xhtml. So i check for validations and if any validation fails,then i return null.

Comment: HHmm do you mean to say that instead of returning null, i redirect the user. Like instead of using `return null` i should use something like this `return "MyDashboard?faces-redirect=true"`. Is it? That is redirect to same page..

Comment: Thanks . Yes you are right. instead of returning null, i used something like this `//return null; return "NewsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate?faces-redirect=true";` i.e, redirect to same page. Now when i click on back button, then the pageExpires message gone. Thanks :)